# Content doesn't fit inside HTML section (can't place image and p on one line)

Tags: html, css, layout

I have a trivial task - place image and text next to each other on one line.
I have absolutely no idea why the means i used before stopped working, i tried everything.

**This is my HTML:**

```
<section class="section-creations" id='creations'>
            <div class="row">
                <h2>My creations</h2> 
                <br>
                <div class="showcase">
                    <img src="resources/img/dornan.png" alt="Talking with sgt.Dornan">
                    <p>"Talking with sgt.Dornan" is a reincarnation of a legendary dialogue from a not less legendary game - Fallout 2. This piece is absolutely gold and will put a smile on everyones face. But now you can rewind that experience in your browser! Done in pure HTML, CSS and JS.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="showcase">
                    <img id='bio' src="resources/img/bioshock.png" alt="Bioshock pipe game">
                    <p id='bio_p'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut illum laboriosam voluptatem ullam id. Rerum ratione repellendus minus, doloribus earum quos, tempore explicabo perspiciatis, optio accusamus, voluptate illum aut quia.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

**This is my CSS:**

```
.row {
    max-width: 1140px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.showcase {
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.showcase p {
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
}

.showcase img {
    width: 550px;
    height: auto;
    margin-right: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
}

#bio {
    float: right;
}

#bio_p {
    float: left;
}
```

**This is how it looks now (HORRIBLE!):**

[image]

*I want the first  image to be on the left side and the p would float it on the right, and do the opposite to the second image.*

Somehow, the content of my creations section crawled out of it and messed up the content in next section. I looked through my HTML and CSS and found no syntax errors, all braces are closed.

What is the problem?

Really appreciate any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. I have added width to `p` tag and add `<div class="clear"></div>` after p tag to clear floating value.

```css
.row {
  max-width: 1140px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.showcase {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.showcase img {
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  margin-right: 4%;
  float: left;
}
#bio{
  margin-left: 4%;
  margin-right: 0;
}
.showcase p {
  float: right;
  width: 46%;
}
#bio_p{
  float:left;
}

#bio {
  float: right;
}
.clear{
  clear:both;
}
```

```html
<section class="section-creations" id='creations'>
    <div class="row">
        <h2>My creations</h2>
        <br>
        <div class="showcase">
            <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff" alt="Talking with sgt.Dornan">
            <p>"Talking with sgt.Dornan" is a reincarnation of a legendary dialogue from a not less legendary game - Fallout 2. This piece is absolutely gold and will put a smile on everyones face. But now you can rewind that experience in your browser! Done in pure HTML, CSS and JS.</p>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="showcase">
            <img id='bio' src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff" alt="Bioshock pipe game">
            <p id='bio_p'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut illum laboriosam voluptatem ullam id. Rerum ratione repellendus minus, doloribus earum quos, tempore explicabo perspiciatis, optio accusamus, voluptate illum aut quia.</p>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Wow, that seems to work. Thank you!
But what was the problem? Some CSS quirks?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
.showcase p {
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 500px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just change the images

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<style>
.row {
    max-width: 1140px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.showcase {
    margin-top: 20px;
    height:230px;
}

.showcase p {
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
}

.showcase img {
   /* width: 550px;*/
    height: auto;
   /* margin-right: 50px;*/
    display: inline-block;
}


</style>
<section class="section-creations" id='creations'>
            <div class="row">
                <h2>My creations</h2> 
                <br>
                <div class="showcase">
                 
                       <img src="pulpitrock.jpg" alt="Mountain View" style="width:50%; float:left;"><!DOCTYPE html>
                 
                       <p style="float:left; width: 40%; margin:20px;">"Talking with sgt.Dornan" is a reincarnation of a legendary dialogue from a not less legendary game - Fallout 2. This piece is absolutely gold and will put a smile on everyones face. But now you can rewind that experience in your browser! Done in pure HTML, CSS and JS.</p>
                                 </div>
                <div class="showcase" style="margn-top:10px;">
                   <img src="pulpitrock.jpg" alt="Mountain View"style="width:50%; float:right;"><!DOCTYPE html>
                    <p id='bio_p' style="float:right; width: 40%; margin:20px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut illum laboriosam voluptatem ullam id. Rerum ratione repellendus minus, doloribus earum quos, tempore explicabo perspiciatis, optio accusamus, voluptate illum aut quia.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, may be this will helpful for you.

```css
.row {
  max-width: 1140px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.showcase {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.showcase img {
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
}
.showcase p {
  float: left;
  width: 46%;
  margin-left:4%;
}
#bio_p{
  float:left;
  margin-left:0;
}
#bio {
  float: right;
}
.clear{
  clear:both;
}
```

```html
<section class="section-creations" id='creations'>
    <div class="row">
        <h2>My creations</h2>
        <br>
        <div class="showcase">
            <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff" alt="Talking with sgt.Dornan">
            <p>"Talking with sgt.Dornan" is a reincarnation of a legendary dialogue from a not less legendary game - Fallout 2. This piece is absolutely gold and will put a smile on everyones face. But now you can rewind that experience in your browser! Done in pure HTML, CSS and JS.</p>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="showcase">
            <img id='bio' src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff" alt="Bioshock pipe game">
            <p id='bio_p'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut illum laboriosam voluptatem ullam id. Rerum ratione repellendus minus, doloribus earum quos, tempore explicabo perspiciatis, optio accusamus, voluptate illum aut quia.</p>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```